# How to remove empty partition in a dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to remove the empty partitions from a Dataframe

We are having two Dataframes, both are created using sqlContext. And the dataframes are constructed and combined as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext}

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

// Loading Dataframe 1
val csv1 = "s3n://xxxxx:xxxxxx@xxxx/xxx.csv"
val csv1DF = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load(csv1) 

// Loading Dataframe 2
val csv2 = "s3n://xxxxx:xxxxxx@xxxx/xxx.csv"
val csv2DF = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load(csv1) 

// Combining dataframes 
val combinedDF = csv1.
                join(csv2 csv1("column_1") === csv2("column_2"))
```

Now the number of partition for combinedDF is 200. 
From [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#other-configuration-options) it is found that the default number of partition is 200 when we use joins.

In some cases the dataframe/csv is not big and getting many empty partition which causes issues later part of the code.

So how can I remove these empty partition created?

Comment: You can `repartition` your dataframe.

Comment: What size I need to provide for repartition?

Comment: @user52045 For repartition I have to provide the new partition size. But its hard to find the perfect size in runtime. For me, I think just removing the empty partition should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `repartition` method can be used to create an RDD without any empty partitions.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35800795/number-of-partitions-in-rdd-and-performance-in-spark) discusses the optimal number of partitions for a given cluster.  Here is good rule of thumb for estimating the optimal number of partitions.

```
number_of_partitions = number_of_cores * 4
```

If you have a cluster of 8 r3.xlarge AWS nodes, you should use 128 partitions (8 nodes * 4 CPUs per node * 4 partitions per CPU).