# Spark how to decide how many repartitions to do for any RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, partition

Spark how to decide how many repartitions to do for any RDD. RDD repartition() takes the number how to come up with the number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of partitions in RDD and performance in Spark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35800795/number-of-partitions-in-rdd-and-performance-in-spark)

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb while deciding partitions .

1. A partition size should be less than 2GB( this restriction comes from spark code ) .
2. In Spark try to keep the partition size = Map Split size = HDFS default block size. Do remember unlike MR  in spark num reducer task >= num mappers
3. If number of partitions is around 2000 then increase the numPartitions > 2000. As spark applies different logic for partition < 2000 and > 2000