# Multiple RDD vs partitioning?

Tags: apache-spark

Does the following line create single `RDD` or multiple `RDD`?

```
 val textFile = sc.textFile("README.txt")
```

My understanding is that it will create a single `RDD` with multiple `partitions` (each `partition` of 128 MB by default) where each `partition` can be further processed on same/different node. Can we ask 
 `Spark` to create mutilple `RDD` instead of single ? If yes does it have any pros/cons ?

Comment: Why would you want to have multiple RDDs instead of a single one ? What do you think is the advantages of that ?

Comment: Exactly this is mine question ? will spark always create one rdd by default ?  Do we need to change this behavior in any scenario ?

Comment: Well you don't need to deal with partitioning data explicitly that usually for the framework to deal with but in some case, you'd need to use custom partitioner in case of skewed data per example. communication is very expensive, so laying out data to minimize network traffic can greatly improve performance. Unfortunately going through all that is quite tedious and broad.

Comment: In all cases, you will never need to define your data into multiple RDDs. They are already distributed, partitioned, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct when you say that Spark will create a single RDD with one or more partitions (which can be controlled by you or will be determined by the underlying datasource) when you read a file using `val textFile = sc.textFile("README.txt")`

Think of it this way: A particular data source will correspond to a single RDD, with the level of parallelism being determined by the number of partitions in that particular RDD. 
If you want to work with another data source, you have the option of making another RDD within the same Spark context.
Trying to make multiple RDD's from the same data source would be completely unnecessary in most situations.

Comment: What is the difference between parallelism and partitions?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Every partition is processed by an individual cpu core. 1 partition => only 1 core utilised. Multiple partitions => Multiple cores utilised for the same job. Hence partitions determine the level of parallelism of the processing job. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35804407/3960021

Comment: Yes, definitely. Thanks. I just wanted make sure I am explaining correct in my answer as I got a downvote. Thanks